# How to reissue a new session cookie when it times out?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I'm having a problem with session cookies that i've not seen (or maybe just not noticed) before.

After a certain amount of time (not sure how long) the session cookie starts returning null to my browser (using Chrome). I can see the cookie on my browser and on the server but it is not updatable.

If it gets to the end of its lifetime, should the server reissue a new one automatically if the browser sends a cookie request that's no longer available?

If not, what's the accepted process to get rid of the expired session cookie and issue a new one?

This is a new server that i've never used before so I don't know if it's just set up differently or i've just never noticed this behaviour before.

Comment: The server won't re-issue a new one *automatically*, you have to code accordingly to check whether the cookie is set and/or empty. If one of those meets that criteria, then set the cookie. That's what conditional statements are for.

Comment: Why not just set the session cookie expiry time to 0? Then it only expires when the browser is closed... i.e. at the end of the session.

Comment: My session.cookie_lifetime is set to 0 by default